# Apex coding structure (What is a static initializer?)

Tags: apex, oop

Static code initializer.

is there any best practice use case for strictly need to be use static initializer?

```
public without sharing class parentcls {
static List<classA__c> classAlist;
static Map<Id, ClassA__c> classAmapById;
static Map<String, ClassA__c> classAmapByName;

static {
    classAlist= new List<classA__c>();
    classAmapById= new Map<Id, classA__c>();
    classAmapByName= new Map<String, classA__c>();
}
}
```

what are the pros?

1. class instance not required when you call utility/parent class, we can call directly with out instantiated (utilclass is best example)

what are the cons?

1. if you have more than one static initializer code blocks.  you can not call directly what ever you want , it runs all code blocks order wise even though if don't need run others

i would like to reopen this question for others(experts) add some more points and use cases. please reopen who ever had access.

Comment: There's not nearly enough context here to really say anything other than what's obvious. It's a class. It has some well named static variables. Ostensibly, when you add things to the list, you'll also add it to the two maps.

Answer (score 2):

This is the static version of instance initialization. If this was a normal instance class, you'd write:

```
public without sharing class parentcls {
    List<classA__c> classAlist;
    Map<Id, ClassA__c> classAmapById;
    Map<String, ClassA__c> classAmapByName;

    parentcls() {
        classAlist= new List<classA__c>();
        classAmapById= new Map<Id, classA__c>();
        classAmapByName= new Map<String, classA__c>();
    }
}
```

The `static {/* code */}` is a static initializer, just as a constructor is an instance initializer.

Your version of the code is functionally equivalent to:

```
public without sharing class parentcls {
    static List<classA__c> classAlist = new List<classA__c>();
    static Map<Id, ClassA__c> classAmapById = new Map<Id, classA__c>();
    static Map<String, ClassA__c> classAmapByName = new Map<String, classA__c>();
}
```

The main reason you'd use a static initializer is when you need something more powerful than a simple assignment as you have here. Since static blocks are actual code blocks, they can include if-else statements, loops, and other things that you can't include in a direct assignment operation.

As for an example of when you'd use a static block initializer, you might want to map account Names to ID values, in which you'd write this:

```
static Map<String, Id> accountNameToId = new Map<String, Id>();
static {
  for(Account record:[SELECT Name FROM Account]) {
    accountNameToId.put(record.Name, record.Id);
  }
}
```

Any time you need to any more initialization than simple asslignment, use static block initializers to finish setting up data structures, etc.

Comment: can i treat as parameter less constructor?  and you mentioned they can include if-else statement ,loops and other things can you please give me use case for when exactly these are useful

Comment: @sdandamud1 Not exactly. Unlike constructors, you're allowed to perform DML and callouts in static block initializers, you can have multiple blocks in a class (they will be called in source code order), you cannot call them from from each other, as they have no name. I added in a simple example for you.

Comment: thank you , now i got your point.

Answer (score 0):

From OOPS perspective (as you have tagged this to OOP).

1. Its a class with with `private` variables, as no modifiers have been defined.
2. It has a static block, which gets executed as soon as this class(No instance creation required) will get called and it will initialize the variables inside the static block and assign to the variables.

For eg:

If you introduce a method to check this:

```
public static String fetchInitilizedVariables(){
    return JSON.serializePretty(classAlist) + JSON.serializePretty(classAmapById) + JSON.serializePretty(classAmapByName);
}
```

And from Anonymous apex check this :

```
System.debug(parentcls.fetchInitilizedVariables());
```

Debug will show : `[ ]{ }{ }`

3. You won't be able to access these variables outside this block as these are private variables.

I can think of these from the above given code.